# Why does my c++ code run significantly faster using Cygwin on Windows, than Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cygwin, c++

I have built a project in c++ and have discovered that on Windows, runtime is  about 120 seconds. Running the same code in Cygwin, compiled for linux, it takes 15 seconds.

I've no idea why this is and I don't expect anyone to be able to provide a completely clear answer with the information available, but I was hoping maybe someone more knowledgeable could point me what to look for?

Comment: What compilers and compiler versions are you using in each environment?